# Open multiple pages with React Router Dom and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I need to create a link which opens more than one route in a new tab when I click on the "Box" component. I'm using Redux
That's the template I'm following, but I'm stucked cause it seems it is not persisting state (which contains authentication datas) opening in a new tabs.

```
const onClickBox = () => {
   onClickPageOne();
   onClickPageTwo();
}

const onClickPageOne = () => {
   dispatch(actions.fetchDataPageOne)
}

const onClickPageTwo = () => {
   dispatch(actions.fetchDataPageTwo)
}

return (
   <>
      <Box
         onClick = {onClickBox }
      >
         Click me!
      </Box>
   </>
)
```

I tried using Link component by react-router-dom but I need only one link for both pages so I don't know what to put in 'to' prop.
I tried using Redirect in onClickBox function but I don't get how to tell him to open in a new page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use single function to dispatch bothh actions from there only

Comment: Ok, but still I don't get how to 'open' two new pages at once.

Comment: you can use window.open in fetchDataPageOne like below 
Ex. window.open('http://yoururl1.com');
    window.open('http://yoururl2.com');